# javascript doesn't work in IE (getElementById)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, internet-explorer

I'm using a form with two submit buttons and JS with 2 functions to use either one.

```
 <form action="" name="submit" id="step_1_form" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
...
<input type="submit" value="Speichern & zurück" class="backbutton" form="absenden" name="saveandback" onClick="saveandback()" />

<input type="submit" value="Speichern & Step 2" class="send" form="absenden" name="saveandfurther" onClick="step2()" />
</form>
```

JS

```
   var form=document.getElementById("step_1_form");
function step2() {
    form.action="step2.php";
    form.submit();
}
function saveandback() {
    form.action="scripts/saveandback.php";
    form.submit();
}
```

It works in Safari, Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE. May you help me to find out which element makes the problem and maybe how to solve it? That would be very nice. Thank you!

Comment: you miss equal sign after id and action in your html.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this mistake happend while i was writing the post, in the original file is the equal sign there.

Comment: Could you please copy-paste your actual code as it is? Don't type it out by hand. It's impossible to know what you have in the real code and what are typos. You're missing an equal sign in `action""` as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. Now it is the original code. Just Copy-Paste excluding the input fields, because i'm sure this has no effects.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you have more than one element with the same id, and IE picks the wrong one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, i found a solution.

It doens't work in IE, when the submit button has the same name as the function. So dont' do this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Speichern" form="absenden" name="saveandback" onClick="saveandback()" />
```

Better do something like this

```
<input type="submit" value="Speichern" form="absenden" name="ANOTHERNAME" onClick="saveandback()" />
```

Answer (score -3):

Try
`var form = document.getElementById("step_1_form");`
Unless you've declared `form` before, this would normally throw an error; Safari, Chrome, and Firefox let errors slip by easier.

Comment: Good Point, but it doesn't fix the problem. But i still keep the var there. This makes sense.

Comment: "this would normally throw an error" — Only in strict mode, which has to be explicitly triggered by the author. Outside of strict mode it implicitly creates a global.